# Import dlopen error when trying to Use tensorflow-text package

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I recently installed the `tensorflow-text` package from source with .whl file.

I used the command

```
pip install /Users/michaelscoleri/Downloads/tensorflow_text-2.8.2-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
```

to download the package.

When importing the packages I get this error:

On importing the packages

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text as text
from official.nlp import optimization


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [23], in <cell line: 47>()
     45 import tensorflow as tf
     46 import tensorflow_hub as hub
---> 47 import tensorflow_text as text
     48 from official.nlp import optimization  # to create AdamW optimizer
     50 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File ~/miniforge3/envs/env_tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_text/__init__.py:20, in <module>
     17 from tensorflow.python.util.all_util import remove_undocumented
     19 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 20 from tensorflow_text.core.pybinds import tflite_registrar
     21 from tensorflow_text.python import keras
     22 from tensorflow_text.python import metrics

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/michaelscoleri/miniforge3/envs/env_tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_text/core/pybinds/tflite_registrar.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: __ZN4absl12lts_2021032410CHexEscapeENS0_11string_viewE
  Referenced from: /Users/michaelscoleri/miniforge3/envs/env_tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_text/core/pybinds/tflite_registrar.so
  Expected in: /Users/michaelscoleri/miniforge3/envs/env_tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
```

I can see the package is installed as **pypi** channel when running 'conda list'.

```
# packages in environment at /Users/michaelscoleri/miniforge3/envs/env_tf:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
abseil-cpp                20210324.2           hbdafb3b_0    conda-forge
absl-py                   1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.8.1            py39hb18efdd_1    conda-forge
aiosignal                 1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
alabaster                 0.7.12                     py_0    conda-forge
appnope                   0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0           py39hb18efdd_2    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
astunparse                1.6.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-timeout             4.0.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
attrs                     21.4.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
babel                     2.10.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
bio                       1.3.9                    pypi_0    pypi
biopython                 1.79                     pypi_0    pypi
biothings-client          0.2.6                    pypi_0    pypi
bleach                    5.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
blinker                   1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
brotli                    1.0.9                h1c322ee_7    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h1c322ee_7    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39hb18efdd_1004    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h3422bc3_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.18.1               h3422bc3_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.6.15            h4653dfc_0    conda-forge
cached-property           1.5.2                hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
cached_property           1.5.2              pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
cachetools                5.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
cctools                   973.0.1             h43ef6ec_10    conda-forge
cctools_osx-arm64         973.0.1             h8e51184_10    conda-forge
certifi                   2022.6.15        py39h2804cbe_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.1           py39h04d3946_0    conda-forge
chardet                   5.0.0            py39h2804cbe_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        2.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.3            py39h2804cbe_0    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
conda                     4.13.0           py39h2804cbe_1    conda-forge
conda-build               3.21.9           py39h2804cbe_1    conda-forge
conda-package-handling    1.8.1            py39hb18efdd_1    conda-forge
conda-souschef            2.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cryptography              37.0.4           py39h4cb6239_0    conda-forge
curl                      7.83.1               h2fcd78c_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.6.0            py39h0ef5a74_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dill                      0.3.5.1                  pypi_0    pypi
docutils                  0.16             py39h2804cbe_3    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.4.8                h6b3803e_0    conda-forge
filelock                  3.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
flatbuffers               1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
flit-core                 3.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.34.2           py39h9eb174b_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h17b34a0_1    conda-forge
frozenlist                1.3.0            py39hb18efdd_1    conda-forge
gast                      0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
gettext                   0.19.8.1          h049c9fb_1008    conda-forge
giflib                    5.2.1                h27ca646_2    conda-forge
git                       2.37.0          pl5321h824b0f5_0    conda-forge
glob2                     0.7                        py_0    conda-forge
google-auth               2.9.0              pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyh8c360ce_0    conda-forge
grayskull                 1.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
grpc-cpp                  1.45.2               h6e39ad6_4    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.45.0           py39hcf421d0_0    conda-forge
h5py                      3.6.0           nompi_py39hd982b79_100    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.12.1          nompi_hf9525e8_104    conda-forge
icu                       70.1                 h6b3803e_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.3                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
imagesize                 1.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        4.11.4           py39h2804cbe_0    conda-forge
importlib_resources       5.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.15.0             pyh736e0ef_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.4.0            py39h2804cbe_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jarowinkler               1.1.0            py39h6e3512e_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.1           py39h2804cbe_1    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
joblib                    1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9e                   he4db4b2_2    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.5              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                4.6.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0            py39h2804cbe_7    conda-forge
jupyter_client            7.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.4.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.10.0           py39h2804cbe_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                2.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         1.0.9                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_widgets        1.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
keras                     2.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.3            py39hab5e169_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.3               hf9b2bbe_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.12                 had6a04f_0    conda-forge
ld64                      609                 h954701c_10    conda-forge
ld64_osx-arm64            609                 h6ce2ded_10    conda-forge
lerc                      3.0                  hbdafb3b_0    conda-forge
libarchive                3.5.2                h69ec738_3    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           15_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h1c322ee_7    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h1c322ee_7    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h1c322ee_7    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           15_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
libclang                  14.0.1                   pypi_0    pypi
libcurl                   7.83.1               h2fcd78c_0    conda-forge
libcxx                    14.0.6               h04bba0f_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.12                 he4db4b2_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         hc8eb9b7_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h642e427_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h3422bc3_5    conda-forge
libgfortran               5.0.0.dev0      11_0_1_hf114ba7_23    conda-forge
libgfortran5              11.0.1.dev0         hf114ba7_23    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 h642e427_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           15_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
liblief                   0.11.5               hbdafb3b_1    conda-forge
libllvm13                 13.0.1               hfd59cb2_2    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.47.0               he723fca_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.20          openmp_h2209c59_0    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h2c9beb0_3    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.20.1               h332123e_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h27ca646_1    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.10.0               hb80f160_2    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.4.0                hcbbed22_1    conda-forge
libwebp                   1.2.2                h0d20362_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.2                h3422bc3_1    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h9b22ae9_1004    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.14               h035c1df_3    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.12               ha287fd2_1    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               14.0.4               hd125106_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                hbdafb3b_1    conda-forge
lzo                       2.10              h642e427_1000    conda-forge
markdown                  3.3.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.1            py39hb18efdd_1    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.5.2            py39hdf13c20_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.5.2            py39h4ee150f_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py39h5161555_1005    conda-forge
multidict                 6.0.2            py39hb18efdd_1    conda-forge
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
mygene                    3.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclient                  0.5.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 6.4.5            py39h2804cbe_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.3                  h07bb92c_1    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nlp                       0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nltk                      3.7                      pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  6.4.12             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.22.4           py39h7df2422_0    conda-forge
oauthlib                  3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h062765e_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1q               ha287fd2_0    conda-forge
opt_einsum                3.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
packaging                 21.3               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.4.3            py39hd2dba81_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
patch                     2.7.6             h27ca646_1002    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.37                hc5de063_0    conda-forge
perl                      5.32.1          2_h9b22ae9_perl5    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    9.2.0            py39h1b8be2f_0    conda-forge
pip                       22.1.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pkginfo                   1.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
progressbar2              4.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.14.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.30             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.30               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.19.4                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.1            py39h9eb174b_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h27ca646_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
py-lief                   0.11.5           py39hfb83b0d_1    conda-forge
pyarrow                   8.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0    conda-forge
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycosat                   0.6.3           py39hb18efdd_1010    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyjwt                     2.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 22.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.18.1           py39hb18efdd_1    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py39h2804cbe_5    conda-forge
python                    3.9.13          hc596b02_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-fastjsonschema     2.15.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-flatbuffers        2.0                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-libarchive-c       4.0              py39h2804cbe_1    conda-forge
python-utils              3.3.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.9                      2_cp39    conda-forge
pytz                      2022.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyu2f                     0.1.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0              py39hb18efdd_4    conda-forge
pyzmq                     23.2.0           py39h8faa4b9_0    conda-forge
rapidfuzz                 2.1.2            py39hd2dba81_0    conda-forge
re2                       2022.06.01           h9a09cb3_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.1.2                h46ed386_0    conda-forge
regex                     2022.6.2                 pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.28.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ripgrep                   13.0.0               h65448a5_2    conda-forge
rsa                       4.8                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ruamel-yaml-jinja2        0.2.7                    pypi_0    pypi
ruamel.yaml               0.17.21          py39hb18efdd_1    conda-forge
ruamel.yaml.clib          0.2.6            py39hb18efdd_1    conda-forge
ruamel.yaml.jinja2        0.2.4                      py_1    conda-forge
ruamel_yaml               0.15.80         py39h9eb174b_1007    conda-forge
scipy                     1.8.1            py39h14896cb_0    conda-forge
seaborn                   0.11.2               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
seaborn-base              0.11.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
setuptools                63.1.0           py39h2804cbe_0    conda-forge
sigtool                   0.1.3                h7747421_0    conda-forge
six                       1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
snappy                    1.1.9                h39c3846_1    conda-forge
snowballstemmer           2.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
soupsieve                 2.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sphinx                    5.0.2              pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    2.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.39.0               h40dfcc0_0    conda-forge
stack_data                0.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.13.2           py39h7b9fbcb_0    conda-forge
stdlib-list               0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tapi                      1100.0.11            he4954df_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               2.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tensorflow                2.8.1           cpu_py39h2839aeb_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-base           2.8.1           cpu_py39h84f6f83_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-deps           2.9.0                         0    apple
tensorflow-estimator      2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-hub            0.12.0             pyhca92ed8_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-macos          2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metal          0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-text           2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
terminado                 0.15.0           py39h2804cbe_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tf-estimator-nightly      2.8.0.dev2021122109          pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               he1e0b03_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.2              py39h9eb174b_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.64.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.3.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.3.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2022a                h191b570_0    conda-forge
unicodedata2              14.0.0           py39hb18efdd_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.9             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
werkzeug                  2.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        3.6.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.14.1           py39h9eb174b_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h27ca646_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h27ca646_0    conda-forge
xxhash                    3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.5                h642e427_1    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h3422bc3_2    conda-forge
yarl                      1.7.2            py39hb18efdd_2    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                hbdafb3b_1    conda-forge
zipp                      3.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.12               ha287fd2_1    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.2                hd705a24_2    conda-forge
```

Any help on how to fix would be great.

### System Details

- MacOS with M1 chip
- Miniforge3 Conda env_tf environment, python = 3.7

Comment: Thanks. Please confirm that "installed from source" means followed [official installation steps](https://github.com/tensorflow/text#installation)? Also, confirm that [Apple's TensorFlow installation instructions](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) were followed.

Comment: when following the official installation steps, the .whl file was never generated. I tried following the build_package file and ran 'bazel build oss_scripts/pip_package:build_pip_package' but recvied error '
ERROR: Analysis of target '//oss_scripts/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted: 
INFO: Elapsed time: 154.243s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (50 packages loaded, 630 targets configured)'

Comment: Where did the .whl come from? You almost certainly have to follow the build instructions. Probably will need to have installed `compilers`, `coreutils`, and `cython` from Conda Forge before doing any Pip steps. Also, unclear why `conda`, `conda-build` and other `conda*` packages are installed in this environment - they only ever need to be in **base**. I'd start over with fresh environment, only installing what you need for this project.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error, Please install `tensorflow-text` and `tf-models-official` using below code and restart the kernel(runtime) before executing the above code:

```
!pip install tensorflow-text
!pip install tf-models-official
```